# After splitting MS Access to SQL Server for execution queries which engine is used

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I would like to know after splitting MS Access to SQL Server for execution queries inside Access, engine of MS Access or engine of SQL Server?

After splitting to SQL Server (back-end), how many users can use MS Access front-end? Is there still limited of number of users when we use MS Access (front-end) and MS Access (back-end)?

Can we transfer queries inside MS Access to SQL Server also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's multiple questions, but I will try to answer them all:

**1. How many users can use an Access front-end simultaneously, after splitting the database?**

That depends: if you're using a single file as front-end (which you shouldn't do), and multiple users are opening that single file, you're still limited by Access's max amount of users.

However, if you give each user their own copy of the front-end, you can have the maximum number of connections for MS-SQL (32,767). However, you can use VBA to open multiple connections to the same server, so that number might be lower in practice.

If you use both MS Access as a front-end and a back end, you will be limited by Access's max amount of users.

**2. Which query engine is used for my existing queries, after splitting my database?**

After splitting your database, all existing queries are still carried out by the JET/ACE (Access) database engine. However, you can change queries into pass-through queries to run queries on the SQL server database. Note that T-SQL is different from JET/ACE SQL, and your queries might need to be adjusted accordingly.

If you want to optimize a specific query, you might move it to the SQL server entirely as a view (which you should do, especially for queries that are used often). This way SQL server can do things like storing query execution plans and caching.

Comment: **Never ever share the front-end!**

Comment: @BitAccesser No, of course not, but just stating that IF you were to do that, the max amount of users would be limited (just like you should really move your queries to the server).

Comment: You should mention that in your answer, or people think it's not bad unless they don't reach that limit.

Comment: @BitAccesser adjusted the answer

Comment: It's worth noting that for "normal queries" (`SELECT foo FROM a JOIN b WHERE c`, though being run by the ACE engine, the grunt work will be done on the SQL Server. Exceptions are e.g. when you use Access functions in the query. @Masoud

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you link via `ODBC`, it depends on your usage. Both methods are availible for`MS-SQL` (what you call SQL Server), but others work too (I use`MySQL`as BE). If you use your old access queries you use jet, but you can use passthrough queries, which are executed on the server.

The number of users is almost unlimited ([32,767 connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-connections-server-configuration-option) thanks to @Erik von Asmuth) and you don't have loss of performance with many users as in ms-access.

Your queries should be moved to the server in long term. but you can start with your old ones (less performance, but compared to a multiuser ms-acces BE it's lighning fast, just a few slowdowns [ms-access-query-on-linked-tables-with-multiple-joins-is-very-slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666642/ms-access-query-on-linked-tables-with-multiple-joins-is-very-slow)).

Another big advantage: you can backup your database anytime, no matter if others are using it.

Have a look at [Move-Access-data-to-a-SQL-Server](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-Access-data-to-a-SQL-Server-database-by-using-the-Upsizing-Wizard-5d74c0df-c8cd-4867-8d07-e6e759d72924?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for howto and [Optimizing Microsoft Office Access Applications Linked to SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204.aspx).

Just try and you will never go back.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify current Microsoft Access.  Pass through and projects are deprecated.   Linking ODBC to SQL Server, MySQL, etc is no problem on the same LAN.

Each user must have their own front end.  Front end file cannot be shared simultaneously by multiple users.

Access is a front end database; queries run in Access.

The simultaneous user count would be defined by the back end server.  There is of course a payload issue as a front end database.  Today's PCs are very powerful but above ~1M active records you should not neglect a reasonable amount of RAM & processing.

Comment: Note that Pass-Through queries are in no way deprecated. ADP projects, yes.

Comment: The queries run in Access but if you place a restriction in that query then that is passed to the server and only the row (or rows) are pulled down the network wire. Some queries such as those with multiple tables (joins) that Access will pull more records then if the query was run server side, but for a basic query run from Access, ONLY the required records are pulled from the server not the whole table. And this includes forms bound directly to a table. If you open the form where a "where" clause, then only the 1 record is pulled from SQL server not the whole table.

Comment: Also, front-ends can be shared simultaneously by multiple users. It's a bad practice, and should be avoided, but certainly is possible.